# Bings.Map Windows 8 metro app : Circle cities

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, bing-maps

I'm currently developping an app where the user can select several cities in the world and check specific information about them.

**I'd like to show which cities are tappable/usable**. To do so, **i'd like to add a circle (filled) on them**. I've noticed I can draw a MapPolygon (and compute my own points, in circle, around the city) but **if the user zoom/unzoom, I need to clean/draw it again** (so it scales correctly) and it could affect performances. (since I have > 100 cities)

**I was wondering if there was a simple way to do it. Like a "good practice" way.** Because I don't think I'm the only one willing to do something like this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the good way to do it: use Pushpin items. They resize correctly after a zoom.

```
Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
MyMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin, location);
```

And just in case you want to increase/decrease the size of the pin:

```
pushpin.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform()
{
ScaleX = 0.7,
ScaleY = 0.7
};
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an idea, rather than an answer, but have you considered using Segoe UI Symbol font instead?

Fonts are better for scaling. Plus, the built in Segoe UI Symbol font has lots of different circles to make good use of. You may even find a better shape.

[image: Segoe UI Symbol font]

Comment: Thx for this interesting alternative, but I found the Pushpin component (which is way better)

Comment: Thanks T.Dupuis, I didn't realise there was a Pushpin feature for Windows. I will remember this in case I ever require it.